# Wix custom install directory Error 2727

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, wix3.9

I have a created a wix installer for my application. 
Everything is working correctly except when I choose **Install for all users on the machine** on the next dialog i choose the installation directory and i Get error.

[image]
[image]
Click Next shows the error above

Windows installer gives the following details
2727 The directory entry '[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YX1i.png)' does not exist in the Directory table.

Product.wxs contains

```
<UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
      <UIRef Id="UISequence" />
    </UI>
```

Wix file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
    <!--Adding dialogs-->
    <UI Id="UISequence">
      <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="AppName" />
      <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced"/>
      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
    Control="Finish"
    Event="DoAction"
    Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>

    </UI>

    <!--Including License agreement-->
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="license.rtf" />
    <!--<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />-->

    <!--Exit Dialog-->
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Thank you for installing this product." />

    <!--Provide Launch Application Option-->
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch AppName" />
    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#AppExeName.exe]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes"/>

  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

If I do not go to advanced, everything works fine. Application is installed for all users.

I looked up everywhere, haven't found y this is happening.

Please help, what have I missed here.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed error 2727 using **APPLICATIONFOLDER**.

before:

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="Company">
       <Directory Id="InstallFolder" Name="MyProgram"/>
      </Directory>
     </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

after:

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="Company">
       <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="MyProgram"/>
      </Directory>
     </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

Addition:
it's strange, but probable when using WIXUI:

```
<UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />
</UI>
```

is optimal to do so:

```
<Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="Company\MyProgram" />
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="Anything"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Actual WIXUI setup folder will be "Program Files\Company\MyProgram", not "Program Files\Anything"

Answer (score 1):

To see the actual error, one must run the installation using
`msiexec /i SoftwareSetup.msi /L*V C:\logs\<logfilename>.log`

In my case when i had 2727 and had no clue , i ran my msi using above command and in the log it clearly said

> **Error 2727 is "The directory entry '[XYZ]' does not exist in the
> Directory table **

So there was a publish event for set target path for directory XYZ but it was **not** present in the directory structure/entries in product.wxs.
So I had to remove the unnecessary set target path publish event and everything fine was.

However to get what is the exact failure run your application using `misexec` like i mentioned in first statement.

Comment: well explanation @jeril